# Losing synchronisation between iPhone and Outlook.com

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, ms-office, calendar

My family is using outlook.com for their calendars. All events are stored there for all the family members, and everyone has access to everyone else's events (at least for reading, some for writing).

All of this works flawlessly with Outlook 2013 and/or the Windows 8 calendar app. And at first, it worked well with our iPhones. However, after prolonged use (a few months) it appears that synchronisation between iPhone and outlook.com stops for whatever reason: New events entered via outlook.com are not synched to the phone and vice versa.

The problem appears to be on the phones' side (not all of them fail at the same time, and synchronisation with all the other devices works). When I delete the outlook.com account on the iPhone and recreate it there, synchronisation resumes (but of course, all the events I entered on the phone are lost) and works again for a few months before failing again.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you tried just restarting the phone when the issue occurs?  I'd try that first _for any issue_ before deleting and re-adding an account.  It would also be interesting to know if that works or does not work to at least temporarily correct this problem.

Comment: Good point – I should have mentioned that yes, I did restart the phone with no effect on the problem.